# Android SE font extremely hard to read

Tags: bug, design

I just opened the Android Stack Exchange site to link someone to it and when I saw it I thought the page hadn't loaded properly. This is what I saw (you'll want to view full size, they're uploaded full-size):

[image]

[image]

Perhaps on some monitors it looks ok, but on both my laptop screen and my external monitor it's *very* hard to read. I have to physically move my head well below my monitor to read the text, especially on the smaller lines, such as the Hot Network Questions sidebar. Comments are almost unreadable.

I'm on Windows 10 Creator's Update (w/ latest updates) and Chrome 59.0.3071.115 if that makes a difference.

It'd be awesome if the font could be changed to something legible. I'm going to tag this with `bug` because I think this couldn't possibly be intentional.

Comment: @DanHulme How is this a dupe?? Look at the screenshots. What I'm seeing is clearly _very_ different to the linked question.

Comment: I disagree, it's extremely similar.  Barring further evidence I think the small differences are due to you using Windows rather than Ubuntu, and I'd suspect the same root cause.